# JProfiler 7.2.2 Remote JVM crashes

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, jprofiler, jprobe

I am attaching Jprofiler Remotely to Linux server. But while connecting eventually remote JVM crashes.
Error Message by JProfiler GUI is as:

```
The network connection has been lost. The JVM might have terminated unexpectedly.

If the JVM has crashed, please try the following strategies:
*Reduce the -Xmx value of the profiled application.
*Change your profiling settings
```

My  Remote  JVM java version is 1.6.0_33
Java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Why it's saying to reduce the -Xmx value of profiled application, or How to resolve this?

Comment: Did you get an hserr_pid crash log on the remote side in the working directory of the profiled application? Please send that file to support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with JProfiler 7.2.3 after specifying JVM GC settings for JBoss 4.2.3:

*-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC*

*-XX:+UseParNewGC*

It worked again for me after removal of these settings.